# How do I migrate a PHP based website to Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a PHP based website, with database connections, form processing, etc, that I need to use a CMS on. I'm trying to use Joomla but after using it for 2 days and reading tutorials on it I'm getting the impression that it's designed to handle static content and that all form processing is to be handled by 3rd party extensions.

Am I getting the wrong impression? Is there a standard way to import a PHP website into a Joomla CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inherited a Joomla 1.5 site a few months ago, so I was in a similar situation to you - where to begin, with lots of questions about Joomla, its ethos, etc. What I've learnt in the meantime is:

- Joomla *is* very heavily dependent on 3rd-party extensions. Some of these are good, some not so good - evaluation and caution is advised.
- Joomla encourages the use of extensions, even for relatively static content. Whether these are full blown 'components', or 'modules', depends on quite how powerful/flexible they need to be.
- The MVC architecture that underlies everything has its positives and negatives. On the plus side, if everything is done consistently, there is a good separation of concerns and - in particular - the template system offers good configurability. On the downside, very simple components/modules have an awful lot of complexity - e.g. just in terms of number of files.
- Joomla is open-source ... sort of. If your familar with the open-source community, you might be a bit disappointed with Joomla, especially when it comes to 3rd-party extensions. Many of them do not embrace the open source ethos, and try to sell code and/or support so, to reiterate, choose your extensions carefully.
- Writing your own extension is fairly simple, especially if you're familiar with PHP. Although the documentation isn't *great*, there are some gems - in particular, take a look at:

  - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1
  - http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase
- When it comes to forms, I'm still undecided. The site I've inherited uses a third-party extension to manage them (mod_breezingforms), but it has its issues. If you have the luxury of trying out several alternatives, take it.
- Run your development site in debug mode. Take a look at database queries. In my own experience, Joomla is very, *very* demanding on the database. For example, I have some pages that make hundreds of calls to the database with every request. Watch out for this.
- At some point, you'll see `itemid` in the URL and wonder what on earth it is. It refers to a menu item. Menus in Joomla are a bit more general than you might think - they don't necessarily represent a 'menu' and they're quite important. For example, the built-in way to include content on a series of pages is for them to belong to the same menu item, so you might need to create 'fake' menus to house content.

Answer (score 2):

Try [MODx Revolution](http://modx.com/software/open-source-cms/modx-revolution/). You can insert your existing php form processors straight into Snippets with next to no modification required, or using the existing [FormIt](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/FormIt) extra. Ajax is easy as pie.

Some docs to get your started:

[Overview](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/An+Overview+of+MODx)

[Making Sites with MODx](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Making+Sites+with+MODx)

[Snippets](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Snippets)

**edit**: apologies if it looks like I've tried to hijack this thread, somehow missed the fact the question is referring specifically to Joomla. MODx is definitely worth a look though ;)

Comment: Is MODx an alternative to Joomla? Guess its back to the drawing board then.

Comment: No need to apologize, Joomla isn't exactly a requirement, which is why I also tagged PHP on this question. I just invested some time learning Joomla, that's all. But I'll see if this MODx is worth further investment, so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many CMS's that can handle forms correctly (maybe only the very very generic ones, such as contact me forms, or shopping carts), but for any other purpose, you probably want to use your own PHP script to handle and process the form.

Nothing is stopping you from having a CMS on one part of the page, and your own PHP script on another.

I've once had a website with 2 different CMS's (Wordpress and Joomla), as well as some custom made pages. Slightly trickier to handle, but it's possible.

Comment: So you're saying I should refer all form processing to custom scripts which redirect back to joomla articles? But how will I load dynamic data into a joomla article? Or is this exclusively extensions stuff?

Comment: You can design your PHP form handler in any way you'd like. You can make it return values that Joomla likes when trying to get the info from Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad to answer. There are few step-by-step tutorial available on the internet for this.

1. [From Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Converting_an_existing_website_to_a_Joomla!_website)
2. [Site Ground tutorial](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla15/static_to_joomla.htm)

If you follow this head start. You are sure to know a lot of joomla along way and convert your website to the joomla.

---

## **BUT, it is easier to build on Joomla rather than convert to it**

Comment: Both of your links describe how to convert a "static" website to Joomla, which is pretty straight forward. The problem is that my website isn't static but database driven.

Comment: @mtanti, Joomla already takes care of the database part. If the previous data is your problem then, you can write separate scripts to do this.

Comment: @mtanti, Just make your current theme to work with Joomla and use Joomla to manage your data. Finished.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking about is the second part of your comment: "use Joomla to manage your data".

Comment: I read both articles and all they show you is how to create articles and link to them from menus. This is not what I want. I want to be able to display data from the database in an article.

Comment: You need to migrate those data to joomla, inorder for joomla to read them. Which is more pain that creating a new article.

Answer (score 1):

The first trick to using Joomla effectively is to not over think things and use code that is proven so you don't have to work so hard.

Your existing content can likely be imported to Joomla just be exporting it to a CSV then importing back in to the Joomla article table.

Form handling is incredibly easy. There are dozens of form handling extensions, some of which do more than you will likely ever need. I use ChronoForms most of the time because it can be made to do basically anything once you learn how it works. I also like RSForms if you need non-tech people to be able to create forms on their own.

"Load dynamic data" in to a Joomla article is not very specific, but I'll take a stab at it. If you mean getting user submissions, then there are front end content submission options built in. If you mean loading data from another source, then you can generally use either a module or a plugin to get that data loaded either on the page or actually within the article itself.

Spend a little time getting to know how it works. Learn the difference between a component, plugin, and module and that will help you get a better grasp of what you can do. Joomla is an extensible framework, there's nothing you can't make it do and many things that are already built for you.

Comment: So I'm right in thinking that the dynamic aspect of the website must be done through 3rd party extensions?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by dynamic aspect of the website. That doesn't really mean anything without context. By definition, every page that Joomla displays is dynamic because it doesn't really exist. It's created from what the URL tells Joomla to load out of the database. In that sense, even a "static" content page is dynamic. What exactly do you mean by "dynamic aspect of the website"?

Comment: Based on the comment above, you want to display some data you have in a database. That data should be migrated to Joomla. Depending on what that data is, you might put it in to articles, or you might need an extension to handle the data. It really depends on what the data is, how you plan to manage it, how it gets in the database, and who is putting it there.

Comment: OK here's an example. In Joomla, can you make a website which shows a list of products in a shop which are stored in a database and allow the admin to update this list? Can I directly manipulate data in my database?

Comment: Ok, first thing you have to understand about Joomla is that it is a framework that comes with basic content management features built in. Rather than trying to make it do everything, Joomla lets you install just the extensions you need.  Next, everything in Joomla is in the database. The Joomla admin is just an interface that allows you to change what is in the database without having to access it directly.
As for your example, if your shop did not need checkout functions, you could make the basic Joomla install do that though an e-commerce extension woul be better suited for that.

Comment: @mtani if those 'products' are just individual bits of HTML content, pretend they're 'articles', and yes, Joomla will handle this out of the box. If you want to represent any custom attributes of those products (price, quantity in stock, etc.) as distinct data, you'll need to use an extension or write your own. You can always directly manipulate data in your database: doesn't mean it's a good idea, though :-)

Comment: I'm getting the impression from people I'm asking about this that everything is just "bits of HTML content". No they're not. The products would be queried which is easy to do in PHP. It seems that doing something like this requires you to find or write an extension which requires me to install this extension every time I update it. Sounds like going in through the window instead of the door.

Comment: I don't think you understand what an extension does. If you need e-commerce, you install an e-commerce component. It will include everything you need for product management, payment processing, shipping, and what ever other functions the developer included. Once it is installed, you access your products through the admin by clicking the e-commerce link. That's it.

Even products are just bits of HTML content when they are displayed, the fact the details are stored in a database are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JUMI](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo0OiJqdW1pIjt9), a Joomla component for embending your own PHP scripts. No scripts modifications are required!